# Running a JAR from the windows contextual menu

Tags: java, windows, jar, regedit

I've got a java application packaged as jar, which I am trying to add as a "right click" option for a specific file type in windows.

I've added the command reg key to the filetype, and the command appears in windows explorer when I rightclick the appropriate file type, but the jar doesn't run successfully.

The value of the (default) command is:

```
java.exe "c:\MYAPPDIR\MYAPP.jar %1"
```

and a command prompt pops up quickly and closes too fast for me to see what is going on.

This exact command works mind in a cmd.exe prompt (where %1 is replaced with a valid file name)

I tried java instead of java.exe, and variations on where the quotations go, but no success.

How do I format the command? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Those quote marks don't look right.  Does it work from the command prompt if you specify the *full* path to the file?  (That's what Explorer does.)  Also don't you need to specify `-jar` to invoke a jarfile?

Comment: What do you mean by the full path to the file? The target file or the jar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Runnable Jar File in order for it to run when you click on it. You can run any jar file by doing `java -jar File.jar`. You can create a runnable jar file in Eclipse, or [you can write the MANIFEST text files by yourself.](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)

Comment: I added the -jar later, but I get the same result without it (and I can run the jar by double clicking on it just fine), that means it's already runnable? Or is that something else?